# Is this the right way to add tooltips in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

By working with laravel we can add tooltips twitter-bootstrap easily, according to my knowledge.

Add the CDN in the app.blade.php file and apply functions on labels to display the message correctly.

Simple example:

app.blade.php file

```
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

<body> 
    <!-- Place the end of the tag - jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({'placement': 'top'});
            });
        </script>
</body>
```

index.blade.php

If we want to display a message on a button we can do this.

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Detalle usuario"> <i class="material-icons">aspect_ratio</i> </a>
```

Comment: Since you've already set the data-placement to top inline style, the .tooltip({'placement': 'top'}) wont be necessary. All else, yes, that's how you properly initialize a bootstrap tooltip regardless of php framework used...

Comment: Does your html code, displays tooltip ?

Comment: It is shown, but I want to know if there is another way, because I see little content in relation to the tooltips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already set the data-placement to top inline style, the .tooltip({'placement': 'top'}) wont be necessary. All else, yes, that's how you properly initialize a bootstrap tooltip regardless of php framework used... – From Valkyrurr.